# Membership system - parents purchasing for children

Tags: members, cartthrob

I am currently extending an ExpressionEngine site to include a membership system.

I'm trying to find a way to allow parents to purchase memberships for their children, ideally multiple children in one transaction. It is for a sports park where the target age group is 6-16.

We are currently using CartThrhob for simple transactions for booking an individual session, so it would be good to make use of this.

We have looked at Membrr however it doesn't look like you can purchase on behalf of another person. I suppose in a way it is like a gift membership system with a cart for mulitple memberships.

Has anyone achieved this type of system? Or can point me in the right direction?

The logic seems straightforward but can't quite work out the best approach with EE.

Many thanks,
Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is simply some system that would allow "one-to-many" parent-child relations between members.

If you're using [Provile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) or [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor), then [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) would work great for that (there are other add-ons that you might find satisfactory, some of them are much cheaper or free).

If you're using only native EE membership system, then you probably need to develop usch addon yourself. Or perhaps use an affiliate system, such as [Affiliate +](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/affiliate-plus), but you will also need custom code to query database.

Then, set up your templates in a way that children could access files that relate to their parents purchases. (You don't probably want to give access to full purchase information, such as invoices, but only actual downloads/tickets, or whatever you are selling)

Comment: Thanks for this Yuri. Just working on this now and have purchased profile:edit and playa.

Comment: I can't seem to work out how to go about relating one member to another within the front end. Only manually within the control panel. I think I need to relate via a field such as membership number, at the point when a member is created? What do you think?

Comment: You need to use profile:edit member registration form, and add Playa field to it - so user could select who referred him. I believe using hidden field with member id should also be possible, but you'll probably need to 'play with the code' a bit to get it working.